Frequent 400 Errors in Blazor App on Azure: 'Ms-AspNetCore-Token' Mismatch
I’m encountering frequent 400 status code errors with my Blazor web app deployed in Azure App Service. The app is using interactive render mode as server and interactive location as global, and it's targeting .NET 8.
In the Log Analytics workspace, I see the error message: 'Ms-AspNetCore-Token' does not match the expected pairing token 'Guid', request rejected. I’m struggling to identify the root cause of this issue.
Could someone help me understand why this error might be occurring and suggest potential solutions?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Extensively searched for details regarding the 'Ms-AspNetCore-Token' mismatch, but all I find is related to the ASP.NET Core app.

Provide more details, Like the error logs and code.

You're going to want to review your Azure App Service's configuration to make sure that it's correctly setup for Blazor deployments.
You can find full documentation regarding this here.
I believe that your issue described above can be solved by setting Session Afinity to On in your Azure App Service Configuration section. It would seem like your clients are jumping between server instances and thus are sending a token that isn't valid for the give instance to the server.
